# Limit of factorials: $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {(2n-1)!}{2^{2n-1}n!(n-1)!}$

Tags: limits, factorial

I'm failing go figure out how to calculate the limit where I have one factorial divided by two at about half its size. The specific limit I'm trying to find is this:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {(2n-1)!}{2^{2n-1}n!(n-1)!}$$

Comment: You can use Stirling's approximation, $n! \approx \sqrt{2 \pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$, whose error bounds are good enough to allow evaluation of the limit. (A quick computation seems to give that this is zero, but it also suggests how you might modify the argument of the limit to give an interesting nonzero limit.)

Comment: Your expression can be made to look a little nicer by multiplying top and bottom by $2n$. We get $\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{2^{2n}}$, the probability of an even split between heads and tails in $2n$ tosses of a fair coin.

Comment: You can similarly see it as $\binom{2n-1}{n}\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}$, the probability of exactly $n$ heads from $2n-1$ fair coin flips.

Answer (score 2):

The ratio of two consecutive terms is $$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}=1+\frac{\color{red}{a}}n+o\left(\frac1n\right),$$ with $$\color{red}{a}=-\frac12.$$
Note that $\color{red}{a}\lt0$ hence the sequence $(x_n)$ is eventually decreasing and its limit is $0$. Furthermore (but this is not needed for the limit), at least in a loose sense of $\approx$, $$x_n\approx n^{\color{red}{a}}=\frac1{\sqrt{n}}.$$
A result which confirms this general approach, and that one could want to memorize because of the ubiquity of its use, is that the mid-coefficient of the $n$th line of the Pascal triangle takes roughly $$\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$$ of the sum of the whole $n$th line, in the sense that $${n\choose \lfloor n/2\rfloor}\approx\frac{2^{n}}{\sqrt{n}}.$$ (More precise asymptotics are available but already this crude one would have solved your exercise right away.)

Comment: The latter observation (or using Stirling's approximation) suggests that the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\sqrt{n} a_n)$, where $(a_n)$ is the original sequence is nonzero but finite. (If my scratchwork is correct, this latter limit is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$.)

Comment: Indeed, $$\sqrt{\pi n}x_n\to1.$$

Comment: Cheers, thanks for the confirmation, Did.